# Added some custom fields but it'snot coming in advanced search

Tags: custom-fields, search

I have 4- 5 custom fields in CIVI CRM but I am not getting it in advanced search.
Please help me I want to search based on custom fields.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to CiviCRM Stack Exchange. Please make sure to select the option "is searchable" for evry custom field, otherwise they will not appear in searches.

Comment: Thanks - please mark the answer as correct for other users.